# ValueError for PyAudio

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyaudio

I was trying out this really simple thing where I use PyAudio to tell the user what he just said but I get some sort of error:
Here is my code below:

```
import speech_recognition

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()
with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
    print("Say Something brozer:")
    audio = recognizer.listen(source)
print("Google Search Recognition think you said:")
print(recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
```

I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ziaullah/Desktop/OMGGGGGGG.py", line 8, in <module>
    print(recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
  File "C:\Users\Ziaullah\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 858, in recognize_google
    if not isinstance(actual_result, dict) or len(actual_result.get("alternative", [])) == 0: raise UnknownValueError()
speech_recognition.UnknownValueError
```

The while prgramm runs without any errors albeit the error shows up when the user stops speaking.

Please help, Thanks

Comment: I've tested your code on ubuntu18.04 with python 3.6.9 and it works fine. You can find more about [this issue here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/383)

Comment: – Ilyes KAANICH Can you tell me where I should have installed and how I should have installed PyAudio and other requirments. I think I messed up there

Comment: pyaudio can be installed using command      
python -m pip install pyaudio
You can follow installation [guide here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/)
If you have a specific error while installing share it